# uiimageview aspectfit question

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I've use a imagepicker to select image from my photo library, then i display that image in an uiimageview. Landscape photo works fine but there is some weirdness to the portrait image. The portrait image suppose to fill up the left and right empty space but it's not.

Cant figure out why the picture wont fill up the left and right space cause the imageview frame did specify the mainScreen bounds.

If i take away the aspectfit then the potrait image is nicely display but the landscape image is stretched to fill up the whole imageview.

My code is as follow:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

UIImageView *selectedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
selectedImageView.image = image;

selectedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[scrollView addSubview:selectedImageView];
[selectedImageView release];

scrollView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Edit: My goal is to display the photo like it's been display in Photos album, start out as fitting in the view and allow zoom in to a certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_bg.png"]];
[logoImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_bg.png"].size.height)];
[mainView addSubview:logoImageView];
```

Comment: Did doesnt work cause my image is large the the frame height would be too large.

Comment: in that case set the scroll view scrollView.contentSize to the image size and the scroll view frame to the rect size you need to display